# PHP file upload error for large files

Tags: php, web, file-upload

I am trying to upload files using php on my local server and save it in the current working directory.The code is working fine for any file type of size less than 2mb but above this size it gives error. I have also  modified the upload and post size in php.ini file,but it was of no help.It gives 4 errors:

> 1. Undefined index: temp in C:\wamp64\www\project\upload.php on line 3
> 2. file_get_contents(C:\wamp64\www\project\project): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\project\upload.php
>    on line 5
> 3. Undefined index: temp in C:\wamp64\www\project\upload.php on line 6
> 4. Undefined index: temp in C:\wamp64\www\project\upload.php on line 18

At end it shows "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.".

I am saving the uploaded file in the same location where upload.php is located.

```
Upload.php:

<?php
$target_dir = getcwd();
$target_file = $target_dir .'\project'. basename($_FILES["temp"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
echo file_get_contents($target_file);
if ($_FILES["temp"]["size"] > 5000000000) 
{
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) 
{
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} 
else 
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["temp"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["temp"]["name"]). " has been 
uploaded.";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you edit the correct `php.ini` (CLI / Server). If you edit the correct one make sure to restart your server

Comment: I have tried this out.But no help. @kerbholz

Comment: can you add some debugging? can you have `print_r($_FILES)` at the top of your script and see if `temp` and `tmp_name` exist at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at your `php.ini` file for these 2 parameters, WAMPServer comes configured with

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 8M
```

Increase the `upload_max_filesize` to a little bigger that the largest file you want to allow to be unloaded. Or a lot larger if you intend to upload more than one file at a time.

Then increase `post_max_size` to a number LARGER that you set `upload_max_filesize` to so for example

```
upload_max_filesize = 80M
post_max_size = 85M
```

`post_max_size` must be larger that `upload_max_filesize` as the file is transported in the POST buffer as well as all other fields that may exist on your form

> NOTE use the wampmanager icon to get to edit `php.ini` and that will ensure you edit the correct `php.ini` there are 2.

```
wampmanager -> php -> php.ini
```

> Also remember to restart Apache once you have edited and saved `php.ini`

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service administration 'wampapache' -> Restart Service
```

Comment: Would the downvoter mind telling me why they thought this answer deserved the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

try to do this points:(ensure if any point is created)

**1- ensure that the method attribute in form is with `POST` value and enctype with `multipart/form-data` value.**

**2- This line `echo file_get_contents($target_file);` *is not here must be placed*
because you are placed it before the file is uploaded, is suggest you to put it at end of your code**

**3-Add this condition at the beginning  if your code**

```
if($_POST["submit"]
{
//Your Code here;
}
```

***and ensure the `name` attribute was added to submit button on a form***

4- Ensure the `project` folder is exist in the same folder which contain `upload.php` file
5-

> **Very Important:**

Ensure to add `\\` ***before & after*** project in `$traget_file` variable to become

```
$target_file = $target_dir .'\\project\\'. basename($_FILES["temp"]["name"]);
```

**the full code work with me**

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"])
{
$target_dir = getcwd();
$target_file = $target_dir .'\\project\\'. basename($_FILES["temp"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
echo file_get_contents($target_file);
if ($_FILES["temp"]["size"] > 5000000000)
{
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0)
{
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}
else
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["temp"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["temp"]["name"]). " has been
uploaded.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="first.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="temp" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope I helped you

Thanks