# Problem with JQuery while submitting form with large size using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form using JQuery AJAX.

```
<form id="form_post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return postNews(this)">
  <div class="upload_form">
    <p><b>Text</b></p>
    <textarea name="text" rows="3" placeholder="Max 200 Characters" required></textarea>
    <p><b>Content</b></p>
    <textarea name="content" rows="10" placeholder="Max 2000 Characters" required></textarea>
    <p><label for="file"><b id="file_message">Choose Image/Video to upload (Max. 100MiB)</b></label></p>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" value="" accept="video/*|image/*" required>
    <div class="box_submit">
      <button id="bt_submit" class="bt_submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the submit code i am using

```
function postNews(form){
var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: "./post.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,,
        success: function (response) {
          if(response == "OK"){
            $("#form_post")[0].reset();
            alert("Uploaded Successfully");
          }
          else{
            alert("Error while posting");
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error Connecting Server");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

  return false;
}
```

When i upload an image there is no problem with it but when i upload a video of size 60MiB,70MiB it is not uploading I can't figure out the problem is it because the file is too large??Are there any JQuery plugins that solves this issue?

Comment: Yes it's very likely a timeout issue, coming from the server, I guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP file upload error for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967983/php-file-upload-error-for-large-files)